# The server tag is not well formed when puting data in label

Tags: asp.net, repeater

In my code I have a repeater and in it's datasorce i have a property FirstName. When I try to get the data from it I get this error:

> The server tag is not well formed.

The problematic code is:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOName" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("FirstName") %>"></asp:Label>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind I fixed it. I just had to replace the quotes to:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblOName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also use a literal control rather than a label in most cases.

A label should really only be used as a 'Label' for another control. So for example a label would be used next to a textbox input to inform people of what info to put in the textbox.

A literal should be used for all other eg non label text.